# /etc/hosts file loses changes on OS X restart

Tags: networking, osx-snow-leopard, apache-http-server, virtual-host

I'm doing web development on Mac OS X (10.6) and to speed this up created a few virtual hosts with short, easy-to-type names like sandbox.drupal7.loc and gwwc.drupal7.loc. I did so following the instructions at http://drupal.org/node/463262 (which involve editing /etc/hosts among other things). Initially  this worked but at some unknown point, it has stopped working.

Viewing /etc/hosts shows that the following line that I needed has been deleted:

```
127.0.0.1       localhost gwwc.drupal7.local drupal6.local newni.loc
```

Somehow it had reverted to an earlier version of the file, containing (among other lines):

```
127.0.0.1       localhost
192.168.0.18    itdb pat
127.0.0.1       newni.loc
208.89.50.22    jura
```

The non 127 IPs are not related to my testing issues and they're just there as an example. I can add back my line to the file and the changes stay until restart, but these changes are not surviving a reboot.

When I add back drupal6.local to the 127.0.0.1 line in `/etc/hosts` fixed things that session 'work' in that it doesn't yield 'Server not found' but it doesn't reach my non-default ghost as configured in /Applications/MAMP/conf/apache/httpd.conf

Could this be somehow related? Is there a robust solution to hard coding entries in `/etc/hosts` on Snow Leopard?

Comment: Would this get a better reponse on another StackExchange site? If so, please move it moderators

Comment: Migrating to Super User on your request

Comment: Couldn't you just add the additional host names to that second `127.0.0.1` line? Sounds a lot like some system service restoring the single `127.0.0.1 localhost` line if changed to prevent things from breaking.

Comment: possible duplicate of [/etc/hosts getting reset in Lion](http://superuser.com/questions/354902/etc-hosts-getting-reset-in-lion) — the `dscl` workaround might work for you.

Comment: I also stumbled upon a blog post than mentioned problems when you saved `/etc/hosts` with the wrong line endings. Make sure it's all Unix `LF`, not `CR`.

Comment: Daniel, thanks for pointing me to that post - it pointed me to the answer given below about making the changes in all hosts.* files in /private/etc/

Comment: @tog22 You're welcome. Note that you need to prefix user names with an @ so they receive a notification about your comments (like I just did), if they're not author of the post you're commenting on. Otherwise they might never see your comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed this by making my changes in all files starting 'hosts.*' in /private/etc/, e.g. /private/etc/hosts.ac (answer found via [etc-hosts-getting-reset-in-lion](https://superuser.com/questions/354902/etc-hosts-getting-reset-in-lion))

Answer (score -1):

As per [this](http://support.apple.com/kb/ta27291) site, I believe you need to edit `/private/etc/hosts` (with **root** privileges of course) and not `/etc/hosts`.

Comment: `/etc` is a symbolic link to `/private/etc`, so that doesn't make a difference.

Comment: Fair enough, didn't catch that one. You did edit it with root privileges though, right?

Comment: Yes, I have explicitly edited /private/etc/hosts (always as sudo) with the same problem.