# Disable website/online store (Urban Outfitters) notifications

Tags: mac, notifications

I've been getting notifications on my Macbook from Urban Outfitters about sales and the like. They show up as banners. I don't see them listed in the notification center in my system preferences. I've already turned off notifications from Mail, Safari, and Google Chrome. I suspect this happened because I accidentally clicked on "allow" when I was on their site months ago, and it asked if I would allow notifications from them. How can I stop getting these notifications?

Comment: If you visit `chrome://settings/content/notifications` in Chrome, do you see a list of sites where you have allowed notifications? You should be able to remove them. I'm not familiar with [settings for Safari](https://support.apple.com/guide/safari/customize-website-notifications-sfri40734/mac#ibrw95cba9bb) but it should be similar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like to stop you: *Stop receiving notifications from a website: Choose Safari > Preferences, click Websites, then click Notifications. Find the website in the list, then select Deny.*

Also: *Change how website notifications appear: Choose Apple menu  > System Preferences, click Notifications, select the website on the left, then change the notification alert style and other settings on the right.*

*Stop seeing requests for permission to send you notifications in Safari: Choose Safari > Preferences, click Websites, then click Notifications. Deselect “Allow websites to ask for permission to send push notifications.*

If you don't want to be bugged with these notification at all or have to worry about accidentally allowing them you can: *Stop seeing Siri Suggestions in Safari: Choose Apple menu  > System Preferences, click Siri, click Siri Suggestions & Privacy, select Safari, then deselect Show Siri Suggestions in App.*

*On your Mac, choose Apple menu  > System Preferences, then click Notifications.
In Notifications preferences, select Do Not Disturb on the left, then set options.
When Do Not Disturb is on, the Notification Center icon in the menu bar is dimmed. You don’t see or hear notifications arrive; they are collected in Notification Center where you can view them later.
You can also turn on Do Not Disturb by holding down the Option key while you click the Notification Center icon  in the menu bar. Or click the icon to open Notification Center, swipe down, then turn on Do Not Disturb. It stays on until midnight, the next scheduled time to turn off (based on settings in Notifications preferences), or you turn it off.*

*Stop notifications
On your Mac, choose Apple menu  > System Preferences, then click Notifications.
In Notifications preferences, select the app on the left, then deselect the Allow Notifications option for the app.
All other notification options for the app are dimmed. You no longer receive any notifications for the app.*

Finally if your also receiving emails from them, here's there unsubscribe page: [link](https://www.urbanoutfitters.com/help/unsubscribe)

Answer (score 0):

If the above is not adequate, edit your /etc/hosts following the instructions at

[How to make changes to Mac /etc/hosts permanent?](https://superuser.com/questions/382744/how-to-make-changes-to-mac-etc-hosts-permanent)

and add the IP addresses of the Urban Outfitters IP addresses to your /etc/hosts file.