# Mac OS X Lion resets my hosts file automatically

Tags: osx-lion, hosts-file

I'm using Mac OX X 10.7.4. I changed my `/private/etc/hosts` file, but when I restarted my computer, my change is gone, like it was reset by the system.

Has anybody else encounter this problem? How did you resolve it?

Answer (score 1):

Are you using Cisco AnyConnect VPN Client? It seems to overwrite `/private/etc/hosts` with `/private/etc/hosts.ac`.

See

- [/etc/hosts getting reset in Lion](https://superuser.com/questions/354902/etc-hosts-getting-reset-in-lion)
- [How to make changes to Mac /etc/hosts permanent?](https://superuser.com/questions/382744/how-to-make-changes-to-mac-etc-hosts-permanent)

Answer (score 0):

Are you using sudo? you need root privileges to modify system files.
Try

```
sudo nano /etc/hosts

sudo nano /private/etc/hosts
```

If you are using AnyConnect then check this
[/etc/hosts getting reset in Lion](https://superuser.com/questions/354902/etc-hosts-getting-reset-in-lion)