# How do I prevent my /etc/hosts file from refreshing upon restart?

Tags: mac, hosts-file, macbook-air

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to make changes to Mac /etc/hosts permanent?](https://superuser.com/questions/382744/how-to-make-changes-to-mac-etc-hosts-permanent)

I have a Mac Air that my little brother uses. Unfortunately, he likes to waste his time on computer games :(

To prevent him from doing that, I added a line akin to the following to my `/etc/hosts/` file:

```
127.0.0.1 somereallyaddictinggamesite.com
```

However, my `/etc/hosts` file always refreshes every time I reboot my Mac, so this line goes away every time I turn on my Mac.

How do I make permanent changes to my `/etc/hosts` file?

Comment: Maybe your little brother found out that this line in /etc/hosts is disturbing the access to his game site and thus he removed it?

Comment: That's impossible :) He doesn't know my admin password, and `su` permissions are required to edit `/etc/hosts`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The hosts file doesn't normally get reset in OS X. Are you using the Cisco AnyConnect VPN client on your computer? It'll reset the file based on /etc/hosts.ac, so if you're using it you need to make customizations both places. See [this previous question](https://superuser.com/questions/354902/etc-hosts-getting-reset-in-lion) and [the Mac OS X Hints article that answered it](http://hints.macworld.com/article.php?story=20111011050950471).